# detecting move in different directions. is it even possible?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, motion-detection

I'm wondering about one thing. Is it possible to detect move of my phone up/down in vertical axis ? I mean straight up or down with standard smartphone ? By "standard" I mean device with out barometer.

My second question. Is it possible do detect move forward/backward *with out* GPS ? I know that I can detect move for example apps that are counting steps are able to detect that I'm in a move with out GPS, but can I get the difference with out using GPS ?

// UPDATE

I understand that I can use accelermeter to detect if the user started movement. But the direction ? What when he will move with constant speed ? How to detect that the movement is in the progress

Answer (score 0):

Considere following points:

1. Suppose An Android Phone is kept parallel to Horizon on Floor.
2. Device origin of it's screen at Top-Left corner of the screen.
3. Has X-axis increasing from left-most of screen(0) to right-most part(getWidth()),
   similarly Y-axis going downwards from the top of screen.
4. So it's Z-axis is perpendicular to device screen, Increasing values of Z as we go in upward direction from screen.

now, If you have (noticeable)change in acceleration of any axis, you can decide the direction of movement's resulting vector. If you own a Samsung's(TM) android device,  go to Dialler and type :

`*#0*#`

and then choose **sensor** ,
observe the values and angles of axis there or see **Graph** mode, you will probably find it useful.